# MySQL get top 3 suppliers from table

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

Hey guys I have an question that I need some support on.

I am trying to get the top 3 suppliers with a single query from a table.

This is the original question: **Who are the top three suppliers by revenue, and where are they located?**

Here is the online table and a query you have to run to create a new table.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

```
CREATE TABLE ByCustomerOrders AS   
SELECT
  o.OrderID
, p.ProductName
, p.ProductID
, Price
, Quantity
, Price * Quantity AS subtotal
, c.CustomerID
, s.SupplierID
FROM OrderDetails    AS od
LEFT JOIN Orders     AS o     ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
LEFT JOIN Products   AS p     ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Customers  AS c     on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Suppliers  AS s     ON s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID;
```

From that, it creates a new table I need to list just the top 3 suppliers, pretty much the supplierID row value that shows up the most.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: I managed to make the duplicate rows with the same value for supplierid show only once. Now I am trying to list them by the most amount `SELECT *
FROM bycustomerorders
GROUP BY supplierid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the 3 top suppliers by revenue (and revenue is the sum of all subtotals) this should work:

```
SELECT s.*, SUM(co.subtotal) as revenue
FROM ByCustomerOrders co 
INNER JOIN Suppliers s ON co.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
GROUP BY co.SupplierID 
ORDER BY revenue DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

PS: You should consider using `decimal` (instead of `float` or `double`) for columns that will represent money or you'll get precision errors and your numbers won't add up.

Answer (score 1):

You have a fairly complex schema that you haven't completely disclosed, so this is a guess.

```
   SELECT COUNT(s.SupplierID) AS supplier_count,
          SUM(Price * Quantity) AS supplier_subtotal,
          s.SupplierID,
          s.SupplierName   /*this is a guess*/
     FROM OrderDetails    AS od
LEFT JOIN Orders     AS o     ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
LEFT JOIN Products   AS p     ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Customers  AS c     on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Suppliers  AS s     ON s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
 GROUP BY s.SupplierID, s.SupplierName
 ORDER BY COUNT(s.SupplierID) DESC
    LIMIT 3
```

This should give you the top suppliers (by units ordered).

The trick here is to use an aggregate query (`SUM() ... GROUP BY`) and then order by one of the aggregate values with a `DESC`ending qualifier.

You might want to troubleshoot this query by leaving off the LIMIT clause until you're sure you're getting the right information.

Comment: In the end I made this `select supplierid, count(*) as TotalOrders FROM bycustomerorders GROUP BY supplierid ORDER BY Totalorders desc LIMIT 3`, is this right? Again, you dont use the giant block of code, that code get queried and makes a new table in the example link.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `ORDER BY Totalorders DESC` is MySQL specific where `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` is portable, however. Beware: you might want to consider making ByCustomerOrders a view rather than a derived table. Derived tables give you the risk of using obsolete data.